# Read & write permissions for project directory in PyCharm

Tags: linux, pycharm, file-permissions

I'm working on PyCharm 2017.2 on Fedora 26.

For some reason, I have read only access to my project directory, which is located on an NTFS partition (Win10/Fedora26 dual boot). Every time I launch PyCharm, it tells me that no project interpreter is set. I set it to python 2.7.13 from the project interpreter setting and when I try to apply the settings, I get the error seen in the screenshot attached below -

[image: PyCharm permission error]

I have tried modifying permissions using chmod (although I'm not sure I did it correctly even though it didn't throw up any errors), it still didn't work.

Any ideas?

Apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't come up with anything helpful via search.

Answer (score 0):

Your `chmod` command should look like:

```
chmod -Rv a+w /mnt/BLABLABLA/Dev/PycharmProjects/CPBootcamp/.idea
```

Then you'll have a verbose output about every processed file in folder. In any case,

```
ls -laR .idea | awk '{print $1, $9}' | grep '\.idea\/.*:\|..[w,-]..[w,-]..[-].'
```

wll give you a listing of all read-only files in .idea and its subfolders.

Comment: I assumed that you want to set write permissions for `all` group, to avoid further complications.

Comment: Hi Leon, Sorry I missed your reply. I did try out the solution you mentioned and got the following resullt - http://imgur.com/a/p0kaP

Comment: Your NTFS partition is mounted in read-only mode. It sometimes happens, when Windows is currently hibernated. Boot back to Windows, shut it down properly, than NTFS partition should mount in read/write mode. If this is the case, you don't need to run chmod at all.

Comment: Hi Leon, I shut down my machine every day. I've done a cold boot several times and booted in and out of Win10 & Linux. Still won't work. I love Fedora, just not able to work on it because of this :(

Comment: When you open your windows NTFS partition in Fedora, are you able to write to it? Probably it's mounted in RO mode. Try to unmount it and then mount back again in RW mode.